# How do I run JUnit 4.11 test cases with SBT?

Tags: junit, sbt

I have the following in **build.sbt**:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test"
```

I noticed that **junit-interface 0.10** depends on **junit-dep 4.10**.  This makes it impossible to compile tests that use **assertNotEquals** which was introduced in **junit 4.11**.

How do I run JUnit 4.11 test cases with SBT?

Comment: It looks like this is doable with **junit-interface 0.11-SNAPSHOT**, but I can't find it published anywhere.

Comment: What SBT version do you use? What happens when you use `force()` to `junit` dependency?

Comment: I'm using sbt 0.13.1.  I haven't tried `force()`.  I found a different workaround.  I'll post the answer now.

Comment: Related question about how to add JUnit support to SBT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174243/run-junit-tests-with-sbt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use junit-interface 0.11 to avoid the dependency on junit-dep:

```
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"
```

UPDATE: junit-interface 0.11 makes this reliable by depending on junit rather than junit-dep.

Comment: Relying on classpath ordering is a pretty fragile way to deal with this.

Comment: @JoeKearney I completely agree. It's a workaround.  junit-interface 0.11 appears to have fixed this. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.novocode/junit-interface/0.11

Answer (score 13):

I would do this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % Test,
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test
        exclude("junit", "junit-dep")
)
```

By excluding what we don't desire, it doesn't interfere.  This doesn't depend on ordering.