# sbt does not find junit tests

Tags: java, scala, junit, sbt

here is my build.sbt

```
name := "tutu"
organization := "com.tutu"
version := "1.0"

// Enables publishing to maven repo
publishMavenStyle := true

// Do not append Scala versions to the generated artifacts
crossPaths := false

// This forbids including Scala related libraries into the dependency
autoScalaLibrary := false

assemblyJarName in assembly := "tutu.jar"
mainClass in assembly := Some(" com.tutu.tutuApplication")


assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x if Assembly.isConfigFile(x) =>
    MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if Assembly.isReadme(ps.last) || Assembly.isLicenseFile(ps.last) =>
    MergeStrategy.rename
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
    (xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {
      case ("io.netty.versions.properties" :: Nil) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) | ("index.list" :: Nil) | ("dependencies" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case ps @ (x :: xs) if ps.last.endsWith(".sf") || ps.last.endsWith(".dsa") =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "plexus" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "services" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case ("spring.schemas" :: Nil) | ("spring.handlers" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
    }
  case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
}



libraryDependencies += "io.dropwizard" % "dropwizard-core" % "1.2.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.squareup.okhttp3" % "okhttp" % "3.0.0-RC1"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % Test
libraryDependencies += "io.dropwizard" % "dropwizard-testing" % "1.2.2" % Test

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-q")
```

My project structure is

- src

  - main
  - ...
  - test
  - java

    - com/tutu
    - api
    - client
    - core
    - db
    - resources

      - PingTest.java

If i run

```
$ sbt test
```

It doesnt execute my PingTest but the @Test is correct defined. How can I make sbt to detect my Java Test classes?

Comment: Is the hierarchy above correct ? It must be `src/test/java/**`. Currently it is `src/java/**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read [this](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#JUnit) about junit-interface.

In short, you need to add dependency

```
"com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test
```

Also, when I resolved similar problem in my project I needed to add also

```
crossPaths := false
```

this is from [this](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface/issues/35) issue comments.

Comment: thanks for your response, I added junit-interfaces and added `testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit)` And if i trigger the tests with `sbt test` i still doesnt execute the tests. But if I trigger it with `sbt clean compile test ` it executes the tests

Answer (score 0):

[This same question seems to have been asked multiple times with slightly different framings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174243/run-junit-tests-with-sbt).

Multiple hits made it hard for me to find the simplest and most current answer.

[This answer by @david.perez seems clear and works with current (2018) SBT 1.1.4.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28051194/1148030)

(That particular question was about conflicting JUnit versions. The `exclude("junit", "junit-dep")` may not be necessary.)

I'll also copy-paste the code here for quick access:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test,
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test exclude("junit", "junit-dep")
)
```